# Spring Roo referencedColumnNames not mapped to a single property

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-roo

I am trying Roo database reverse engineering and I had a problem with my first real database. For this question, I created a minimal example showing the problem. In the DB there is a sl_person table a sl_group table and a bridge table sl_person_group, since a person can belong to 0 or more groups.

```
CREATE DATABASE `rooperson` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sl_group` (
`id_group` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
`description` text,
UNIQUE KEY `id_group_idx` (`id_group`),
UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sl_person` (
`id_person` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
`surname` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_person`),
KEY `name` (`name`),
KEY `surname` (`surname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5727 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sl_person_group` (
`id_person` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`id_group` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
UNIQUE KEY `id_person_group_idx` (`id_person`,`id_group`),
KEY `id_group` (`id_group`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET;

ALTER TABLE `sl_person_group`
ADD CONSTRAINT `sl_person_group_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_group`) REFERENCES `sl_group` (`id_group`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `sl_person_group_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_person`) REFERENCES `sl_person` (`id_person`);
```

In Eclipse I create a new Spring Roo project with Spring Source Tool Suite: File -> New -> Project -> Spring Roo Project

```
Project Name: rooperson
Top level package name: org.obliquid.rooperson
Next -> Finish
```

Then in roo shell I type:

```
persistence setup --database MYSQL --provider HIBERNATE
database properties set --key database.password --value xxxxx
database properties set --key database.username --value rooperson
database properties set –key database.url –value jdbc:mysql://localhost/rooperson?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&characterEncoding=UTF-8
database reverse engineer --schema PUBLIC --package org.obliquid.rooperson.domain
web mvc setup
```

Then I fixed [a small problem with stylesheets](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?111961-Roo-%281.1.5%29-generated-proj-s-have-missing-style-sheets).

However, when I try to start GlasshFish 3.1.1, the application doesn't start with the following error.

INFO: 2011-09-11 20:42:59,562 [admin-thread-pool-4848(3)] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' 
defined in file [/usr/local/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps/rooperson/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file 
[/usr/local/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps/rooperson/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is **org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(id_group) 
of org.obliquid.rooperson.domain.SlPersonGroup.idGroup referencing org.obliquid.rooperson.domain.SlGroup not mapped to a single property**
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)

The generated file SlPersonGroup_Roo_DbManaged.aj starts with:

```
privileged aspect SlPersonGroup_Roo_DbManaged {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_group", referencedColumnName = "id_group", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private SlGroup SlPersonGroup.idGroup;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_person", referencedColumnName = "id_person", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private SlPerson SlPersonGroup.idPerson;
```

How can I solve the problem? If I should provide more information let me know.

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you figure it out? If so, would love if you'd share.

Comment: No, I didn't... I will try again when Roo 1.2 will be out.

Answer (score -3):

Similar problem here. It seems this version of Roo has a problem with composite primary keys (as in your sl_person_group table).

While making the key refer to a single column will stop this from happening, unfortunately it's probably not what your data model calls for.